# Java noobie: for loop to call methods not working

Tags: java, for-loop, methods

I know this should be basic but I cannot figure it out (I'm still a beginner). What I want the code to do is:
/*Take user input for population and land area for 3 countries.
* Calculate the population density (i.e. population/land area) for every country,
* Output the average population density for all 3 countries.
*/

For some reason my For loop to call the methods does not work. It only calls the first country method (USA, Canada or Mexico), then stops. Any help greatly appreciated! Here is my code:
(link)
[jdoodle.com/a/oQY](http://jdoodle.com/a/oQY)

(code)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Q8_PopAndLandArea2 {
    static String pplPerMile = " person/s per square mile.\n";
    static Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Q8_PopAndLandArea2 obj = new Q8_PopAndLandArea2();
        obj.CountryCaller();
}


String userSelected;
public String CountryCaller() {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter one of these 3 countries: \n1.USA \n2.Canada \n3.Mexico");
        userSelected = x.next();
        if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("USA")) {
            return "The population density of the USA is " + USA();
        } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Canada")){
            return "The population density of the Canada is " + Canada();
        } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Mexico")){
            return "The population density of the Mexico is " + Mexico();
        } else {
            System.out.println("I don't understand. Care to try again?");
            String tryAgain2 = x.next();
            if (tryAgain2.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            } else {
                CountryCaller();
            }               
        }       
    } return "The average is"+ popDensity();    
}


    public int USA() {
        int calcUSA2 = 0;
        String calcUSAstr = "The population density of the USA is ";
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popUSA = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaUSA = x.nextInt();
         calcUSA2 = popUSA/areaUSA;
        System.out.println(calcUSAstr + calcUSA2 + pplPerMile + calcUSA2);
        return  calcUSA2;
        } 


    public int Canada() {
        int calcCanada2 = 0;
        String calcCanadaStr = "The population density of Canada is ";
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popCanada = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaCanada = x.nextInt();
        int calcCanada = popCanada/areaCanada;
        System.out.println(calcCanadaStr + calcCanada + pplPerMile);
        return calcCanada2;
    }

    public int Mexico() {
        int calcMexicio2 = 0;
        String calcMexicioStr = "The population density of Mexico is ";
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popMexico = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaMexico = x.nextInt();
        int calcMexicio = popMexico/areaMexico;
        System.out.println(calcMexicioStr + calcMexicio + pplPerMile);
        return calcMexicio2;
    }

    public int popDensity() {
        int calcAve = USA()  + Canada() + Mexico() / 3;
        System.out.println("The average is " + calcAve);
        return calcAve;
    }

}
```

Comment: include the code in the question

Comment: Thank you, @XtremeBaumer. I've done so now. :)

Comment: The `return` statements end the method execution (and its `for` loop of course).

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I'm having trouble finding a good question to dupe it against. But yes, the issue is the use of `return`.

Comment: try using a do while loop for these type of conditions.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I guess I really am not understanding these concepts well enough yet. I am trying to get the local variables returned out to the other methods, essentially to make them "public."

Comment: So CountryCaller() method should be void then..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors, I think you don't get at all the concept of OO programming (or just Java structure).

1. First of all, when you do a return inside a loop, it will end. Is like a break. You should remove the return statments inside the loop.
2. When you return a string, you have to do something with it. The method returns the average, but you don't pop it to the user. You where doing it in popDensity().
3. PopDensity() method was calling another time to the countries methods, so you would have to introudce again the params. You should store the result of the coutries method returns, to avoid calling them again.
4. You were calling CountryCaller() again, recursivity, so you were starting the loop again... I think you want to stop the loop not to start it again.
5. In Mexico and Canada methods, you were not returning the real result.
6. You were doing some duplicates outs to user, care of this.

Here is the correct code, please compare it with yours, please compare with yours code and try to uderstand all, if there is something you don't get, please ask it in a comment :).

Code:

```
package massilia.export.promotion;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q8_PopAndLandArea2 {
    static String pplPerMile = " person/s per square mile.\n";
    static Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q8_PopAndLandArea2 obj = new Q8_PopAndLandArea2();
        obj.countryCaller();
    }

    String userSelected;

    void countryCaller() {
        int i;
        int totalDensity = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            int actualDensity = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter one of these 3 countries: \n1.USA \n2.Canada \n3.Mexico");
            userSelected = x.next();
            if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("USA")) {
                actualDensity = USA();
            } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Canada")) {
                actualDensity = Canada();
            } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Mexico")) {
                actualDensity = Mexico();
            } else {
                System.out.println("I don't understand. Care to try again?");
                String tryAgain2 = x.next();
                if (tryAgain2.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            totalDensity += actualDensity;
        }
        System.out.println("The average is" + totalDensity / 3);
    }

    public int USA() {
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popUSA = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaUSA = x.nextInt();
        int calcUSA = popUSA / areaUSA;
        System.out.println("The population density of the USA is " + calcUSA + pplPerMile + calcUSA);
        return calcUSA;
    }

    public int Canada() {
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popCanada = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaCanada = x.nextInt();
        int calcCanada = popCanada / areaCanada;
        System.out.println("The population density of Canada is" + calcCanada + pplPerMile);
        return calcCanada;
    }

    public int Mexico() {
        System.out.println("Enter the approximate population: ");
        int popMexico = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the land area of the country (in sq miles): ");
        int areaMexico = x.nextInt();
        int calcMexicio = popMexico / areaMexico;
        System.out.println("The population density of Mexico is " + calcMexicio + pplPerMile);
        return calcMexicio;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alberto! I have much to learn, you are correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

The return statments are doing your for stop.

You should change your return statment that are inside your for by prints.

Try this:

```
public String CountryCaller() {
    int i;
    int totalDensity = 0;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter one of these 3 countries: \n1.USA \n2.Canada \n3.Mexico");
        userSelected = x.next();
        if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("USA")) {
            totalDensity += USA();
            System.out.println("The population density of the USA is " + USA());
        } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Canada")){
            totalDensity += Canada();
            System.out.println("The population density of the Canada is " + Canada());
        } else if (userSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Mexico")){
            totalDensity += Mexico();
            System.out.println("The population density of the Mexico is " + Mexico());
        } else {
            System.out.println("I don't understand. Care to try again?");
            String tryAgain2 = x.next();
            if (tryAgain2.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            } else {
                CountryCaller();
            }               
        }       
    } return "The average is"+ totalDensity/3;  
}
```

Comment: Much thanks, Alberto! I edited the code as you suggested and it did indeed help, _but_ now it calls the 3 "country" methods, then goes back and calls the CountryCaller() method, effectively starting over...and stops with USA for whatever reason. :/

Comment: I would reply another time with your correct code, and a little bit more of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the "return" keyword.
When you call return, your program exits its current method (even if it's inside a loop).
So what you're actually doing is entering in the if condition for USA and exiting the method by returning a string.
My advice is: only use "return" inside a loop when you know've got the necessary value/condition and you want to exit the method.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. What was really confusing me is how to properly return values _out_ of a method so that the variables can be used in other methods (calculating average of the 3 countries' population density, in my case here). I thought I should use the return *var* but I suppose I have to use the return methods themselves..?

Comment: You don't need to have a return value for all of your methods. Also, you should develop methods that do something specific (like you USA, Candada and Mexico).

Comment: **Comment fix:** You don't need to have a return value for all of your methods. Also, you could refactor your three country methods to a generic one that would return the correct value to each contry as they share a lot of similar code. I believe your `CountryCaller` method should not return a value (a void method) and just work the logic behind merging and processing your contries infos. So far you don't know much of Java so it is a OK solution, but you should definetly look at Arrays and Dictionaries since they would be a better and more logic approach to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement terminates the execution of a function and returns control to the calling function.

Have a look at your `CountryCaller` method - you are jumping out of it ( `return`ing ) from inside your loop - this will cause the loop to terminate

Comment: I don't know Java, I was just wondering, that recursive call else CountryCaller(); at the end of CountryCaller, does that mean if it recurses 3 times, when the stack unwinds it'll print out "The average is" three times?

Comment: Thank you, Dave. To be clear, function and method are the same thing in Java, correct?

Comment: You can think of them as being the same thing, but I think you should really use the word "method".